# Setup redirect URL with correct port for django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I tried to follow the tutorial at https://wsvincent.com/django-allauth-tutorial-custom-user-model/

My authorized desired callback URL is

```
https://localhost:2053/accounts/google/login/callback/
```

Under **Site**, I fill up as follow

[image]

This is how the table looks like

```
snapweb=# select * from django_site
snapweb-# ;
 id |  domain   |    name
----+-----------+-------------
  1 | 127.0.0.1 | example.com
(1 row)
```

I have the following code in `settings.py`

```
# DJANGO-ALLAUTH SETTINGS
# Site id required for using 'sites' framework with django-allauth
SITE_ID = 1    # 1 is for 127.0.0.1
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL='https'
```

Then, I try to login to Google by clicking on the following link

```
<p><a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}">Log In with Gmail</a></p>
```

However, I get the following error from Google

[image]

It seems that `django-allauth` is passing the wrong redirect URL without correct port (`https://localhost/accounts/google/login/callback/`).

The correct URL should be

```
https://localhost:2053/accounts/google/login/callback/
```

But django-allauth is passing

```
https://localhost/accounts/google/login/callback/
```

May I know how I can pass the correct redirect URL to Google?

---

What I had tried?

For `Site`, I had tried various value like

```
snapweb=# select * from django_site
snapweb-# ;
 id |  domain        |    name
----+----------------+-------------
  1 | 127.0.0.1:2053 | example.com
(1 row)

snapweb=# select * from django_site
snapweb-# ;
 id |  domain        |    name
----+----------------+-------------
  1 | localhost:2053 | example.com
(1 row)
```

But still, Google is complaining receiving `https://localhost/accounts/google/login/callback/`

Comment: Could you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The comment on [this url](https://wsvincent.com/django-allauth-tutorial-custom-user-model/) from **Aniket A. Aryamane** says how to solve the problem:

> While creating Oauth 2.0 client ID, mention the "Authorized redirect
>   URIs" as: "http://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/"
>   instead of "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/"
>
> 2) Update the Django admin - "Sites" domain name to "localhost"
>   instead of "127.0.0.1"
>
> Then it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the problem is facebook, google or any other social media login won't support **localhost**. You need to explicitly define a sub-domain or a particular dedicated IP address. Can you please try using a particular domain or dedicated IP?

Or else you can use this website for development https://tolocalhost.com/
and then configure it as per the you development environment. i.e the port and hostname.